# Is it possible to identify the wasp species/family by the nest?

Tags: wasps

I've seen a weird looking wasp nest recently.
Here's the picture:

[image: Wasp nest]

I'm saying weird because it's the first time I see a nest that isn't a ball made of grey paper. Although this one is also made of paper, I don't understand where does the colour come from.

Is it possible to say, **what species or family does it belong to**?

(location is the North-West of Russia, close to Saint-Petersburg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my bad. Should've googled better.
It seems that it might be a **common wasp** aka *Vespula vulgaris*. It's said that the colour of the nest is caused by material being collected from the rotten tree trunks.

See the identified sample:

[image: Common wasp nest]

It's said that they don't make nests in houses too often that's why I'm not accustomed to the look of the nest.